# Finding the global maxima when 1st derivative has a singularity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, maxima-minima

Let $f$ be real function which is differentiable everywhere except at a finite set of singularity point $S$.

Assume that $\lim_{x\to \alpha} f(x) = -\infty$ for every $\alpha \in S$. Is it possible to prove that the global maxima is a local maxima? (i.e it can be found with the first and second derivative test?)

I'm not very strong in analysis so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. After the last singularity point, the function could increase so $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. Here, there would be no global maximum. **If** a global maximum exists, it occurs at a local maximum since this is true of all differentiable functions.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It just so happen that in the function I'm working with, there is the global maximum. I also think that it occurs at a local maximum. But I can't prove it.